# How to get smooth GPU accelerated video playback with Subtitles using Media Player Classic

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, hdvideo, video-playback, media-player-classic

I run Windows 7 x32 in my Dell Studio 1555 laptop having ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4500/5100 Series Graphics card. I have the latest drivers installed, even then, I got some stuttering, when I try to play HD videos (here in this case I tried an MKV file, 1920x800) using WMP + Win7codecs 3.8.7 final by shark007. I tried other HD players and found not much useful. After some googling, I found an article **[Play 1080p x264 smoothly using GPU acceleration](http://www.lowfps.com/play-1080p-x264-smoothly-using-gpu-acceleration)**. I downloaded Media Player Classic: Home Cinema (GPU accelerated) and installed, and changed output to **EVR** as mentioned in the article to get best GPU acceleration (and I used directx 9 option for RealMedia Video and QuickTime Video, not mentioned in the article).

[image: Settings]

The trick worked and I get a flawless video output. But the problem is no subtitles then. I switched it to **VMR9 (renderless)** and then subtitles came back. But the video playback again lost some performance and got some stuttering. So, the questions are;

1. Is EVR (Vista/.Net3 the better option for my PC)?
2. If I use EVR option, how can I get subtitles?
3. Is DirectX 9 the better option for RealMedia Video and QuickTime Video?
4. Any other settings available for smoother playback of 1080p videos.

Comment: *I downloaded Media Player Classic: Home Cinema (GPU accelerated) and installed, and changed output* -> don't. MPC:HC settings come with GPU acceleration without you having to do anything.

Comment: @Sathya whats EVR? and what about DirectX options?

Comment: EVR is the Enhanced Video Renderer [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694916(v=vs.85).aspx]. As long as the DXVA filters in the "Internal Filters" tab are checked and EVR is used, the GPU handles all of (supported) video decode and processing/rendering tasks.